# Unexpected side effect in computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not sure why i'm getting an unexpected side effect in computer property error with the code below.

Error:

```
 ✘  https://google.com/#q=vue%2Fno-side-effects-in-computed-properties  Unexpected side effect in "orderMyReposByStars" computed property            
  src/components/HelloWorld.vue:84:14
        return this.myRepos.sort((a, b) => a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count)
```

html:

```
<div v-if="myRepos && myRepos.length > 0">
  <h3>My Repos</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="repo in orderMyReposByStars" v-bind:key="repo.id">
      <div class="repo">
        {{repo.name}}
        <div class="pull-right">
          <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
          <span class="bold">{{repo.stargazers_count}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      myRepos: null,  <-- THIS IS ULTIMATELY AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS
    }
  },
  computed: {
    orderMyReposByStars: function () {
      return this.myRepos.sort((a, b) => a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count)
    },
...
```

From what I can tell this looks correct according to the docs here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results

Answer (score 54):

`.sort` mutates the original array.

To avoid it, clone the array before sorting it.

`.slice()` is 1 of the simplest way to clone array. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20547803/5599288).

`return this.myRepos.slice().sort((a, b) => a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count)`

---

On a side note, `null.sort()` or `null.slice()` will throw an error. Perhaps it would be better to set the initial value of `myRepos` to an empty array `[]` instead of `null`

Comment: Could do that. What i didn't show is that i'm actually using `v-if="myRepos && myRepos.length > 0` prior to the html I've pasted in my question

Answer (score 2):

### 2023 easy & readable solution...

Just the use [**`spread`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax:

```
computed: {
  orderMyReposByStars: function () {
     return [...this.myRepos].sort((a, b) => a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count)
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is to add a filter before the sort.

`Array.filter(() => true).sort((a, b) => a.menu_order - b.menu_order);`